# Can I memcpy std::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, data-representation

First off, what is the typical implementation of a `std::weak_ptr`? Particularly is `std::weak_ptr` just a pointer to the control block of a `std::shared_ptr`?

If all the `std::shared_ptr` references are gone is the internal control block deleted? If so, how does `std::weak_ptr::expired()` function properly if that memory is re-purposed?

---

I have an object that contains a `std::weak_ptr`, and I want to `memcpy` the object to a buffer to be processed later. Is doing so going to break the internal workings of the smart pointer in some way?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable#Notes . [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) has nontrivial constructors, if I read it correctly.

Comment: @Justin The presence of non-trivial constructors isn’t the issue, only the presence of non-trivial copy or move constructors. However, it’s impossible for an implementation to have a trivial `std::weak_ptr` copy constructor, since copying a `weak_ptr` needs to modify the control block.

Comment: "_Particularly is std::weak_ptr just a pointer to the control block of a std::shared_ptr_" not "is a" but **contains a**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When all `std::shared_ptr` objects are gone, the control block still exists (that's how `std::weak_ptr`'s work), only the referenced object is deleted.

Now, a C++ object can be safely copied via `std::memcpy` [only if it is trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). Checking the requirements of [`TriviallyCopyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) concept, we see that `std::weak_ptr` does not satisfy it due to having a non-trivial copy constructor. In fact, this constructor will increase the weak-pointers-counter inside the control block, so copying it with `std::memcpy` would break its invariants.

To be honest, storing an `std::weak_ptr` in a raw buffer sounds like a terrible idea in usual code. Buffers are normally used for serialization, sending/writing data, etc, and all these tasks are nonsensical for a smart pointer. If, however, you are absolutely sure that you need to store it in a buffer, you need [placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

```
std::weak_ptr<T> the_one_i_want_to_copy;

std::weak_ptr<T> * buffer = ...;
new (buffer) std::weak_ptr<T> { the_one_i_want_to_copy };
```

Notice the `(buffer)` after `new`: it tells `new` not to allocate the memory, but to use an already prepared place (thus **place**ment new). When preparing `buffer`, be sure to provide the required size and alignment.

Comment: There are other uses for raw buffers, like `optional` or `variant`. But it is at least a bit weird. If you really need to copy the `weak_ptr` into a buffer, though, the correct tool is placement new.

Comment: @DanielH A very good point! I will add this to the answer, thank you.